# Strange compiler error with this lines in my header file

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors

I am getting compiler errors when I try to compile my `system.h` header file, which has the following lines, starting at line number 63:

```cpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#undef fprintf
#ifdef FILE
  int fiprintf(FILE *, const char *format, ...)
    __attribute__((format(fprintf, 2, 3)));  /* 2=format, 3=params */
#endif
#define fprintf fiprintf
#undef sprintf
int siprintf(char *, const char *format, ...)
    __attribute__((format(printf, 2, 3)));  /* 2=format, 3=params */
#define sprintf siprintf
#undef printf
int iprintf(const char *format, ...)
    __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));  /* 1=format, 2=params */
#define printf iprintf

#undef vfprintf
#define vfprintf vfiprintf

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif /* __cplusplus */
```

The errors are:

```
system_description/system.h: Assembler messages:
system_description/system.h:74: Error: unrecognised instruction int
system_description/system.h:75: Error: unrecognised instruction __attribute__((format(printf,
system_description/system.h:78: Error: unrecognised instruction int
system_description/system.h:79: Error: unrecognised instruction __attribute__((format(printf,
```

The first line number of the code below is @63.

This is the file which has been the same and compiling fine previously until recently when I started seeing this error. I think it might be due to some compiler options which I'm forgetting to set or have gotten modified inadvertently.

Comment: See how the first line of the error says "Assembler messages"?  Somehow, this C code is being fed directly to the assembler, rather than being translated by the C compiler first.  This can't normally happen.  In order to help you further, we would need to see the COMPLETE AND UNEDITED build log (it may be very long, but we really do need to see all of it) and it would also help to see your Makefiles.

Comment: By *when I try to compile my system.h header file* do you mean *when I try to compile a file that includes my system.h header file*? One does not normally compile a header file.